# xsd: Enforce single occurrence of attibute value in set of elements

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I'm new in the field of xsd files and stranded with a question.
I have an xml file like this:

```
<config version="1.6">
  <properties>
    <parameter name="path">Hello</parameter>
    <parameter name="name">World</parameter>
    <parameter name="run">13</parameter>
    <parameter name="rate">37</parameter>
  </properties>
</config>
```

I already created a xsd to validate the list of parameters with the 'name' attribute:

```
<xs:element name="config" type="configType"/>

<xs:complexType name="parameterType">
  <xs:simpleContent>
    <xs:extension base="xs:string">
      <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="name"/>
    </xs:extension>
   </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="propertiesType">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element type="parameterType" name="parameter" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
 </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
  
<xs:complexType name="configType">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element type="propertiesType" name="properties"/>
  </xs:sequence>
  <xs:attribute type="xs:float" name="version"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

What I need in addition, is to ensure that exactly one parameter element with the attibute name="path" exists. Unfortunately can not change the input xml.

Do you have any ideas?

EDIT: Removed xsd 1.1 tag, due to your tool "XML Check" not supporting xsd 1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using XSD 1.1 as the tag suggests then it's easy:

```
<xs:assert test="count(parameter[@name='path'])=1"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion, Yes, I added the xsd 1.1 tag, because I thought there should be a way with the assertions. I wanted to test this statement (and did some google), but it seems that xsd 1.1 is not supported by the tools I use, "XML Check".  I'm sorry, didn't knew 1.1 is not widely supported. At least it seems so. Is there also a way without with xsd 1.0?

Comment: Alright, then we have to look for a XSD 1.1 tool or skript the  remaining checks in another way. I'll accept your answer, since it's the only way. Thank you for you help.